# NTP configuration not recognized?

Tags: linux, redhat, ntp, ntpd

I'm trying to configure NTP on my machine but it seems that the parameters I set are not being read by the system. Below is my `/etc/ntp.conf` file. (I applied the most basic configuration to eliminate other issues)

```
server 10.45.68.47
server 127.0.0.1
```

After I set the above configuration, I restart the ntpd process by doing the following:

```
service ntpd restart
```

And then I get the following output:

```
Shutting down ntpd:                                        [  OK  ]
ntpd: Synchronizing with time server:                      [FAILED]
Starting ntpd:                                             [  OK  ]
```

Moreover, I can see the following in `/var/etc/messages`:

```
 Apr  2 10:54:07 hsystem1a ntpd[21067]: ntpd exiting on signal 15
 Apr  2 10:54:07 hsystem1a ntpdate[21537]: can't find host ntpServer1 
 Apr  2 10:54:07 hsystem1a ntpdate[21537]: can't find host ntpServer2 
 Apr  2 10:54:07 hsystem1a ntpdate[21537]: no servers can be used, exiting
```

So it seems that the `ntpServer1` and the `ntpServer2` are being read from somewhere instead of the IPs I configured in `/etc/ntp.conf`.

**NOTE**: I done `init 6` on the machine just in case.

**UPDATE**
It seems that the target server is reachable but it is not synchronized. I know that if the synchronization is successful, then "*" should appear near the server name:

```
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 omap            127.0.0.1        7 u   50   64  377    0.269  -21536.   4.813
```

Answer (score 6):

On Red Hat there are a couple of things that happen when you do `service ntpd restart`.

1. `ntpd` is stopped
2. `ntpdate` is run to set an initial time. This is because, by default, `ntpd` will not adjust the system time past a certain threshold. `ntpdate` does a one off time set using a specified time server. You can do this manually with `ntpdate 10.45.68.47` as long as ntpd isn't running.
3. `ntpd` is started again

ntpd's servers are specified in `/etc/ntp.conf` but `ntpdate` takes them from a file called `/etc/ntp/step-tickers`. If you look in the `ntpd` script in `/etc/init.d` you'll notice that `ntpdate` uses this file if there is anything in it (if it is empty, the `ntpdate` step is skipped). You can put your time servers in here:

```
server 10.45.68.47
```

and `ntpdate` will use them to set the initial time.

As an aside, you shouldn't have localhost as a time server. Use a local server and maybe some servers from the [ntp pool project](http://www.pool.ntp.org/en/). Make sure they are geographically close to you for best results. Also, I would re-instate the default Red Hat config as it has some sensible defaults i.e. not allowing other servers to set the time on your server.

Comment: Hi and thank for your very detailed answer! However when I added my IPs to the `/etc/ntp/step-tickers`, the servers changed but now I see the following in the `/var/log/messages/`: `Apr  2 14:13:22 hsystem1a ntpdate[12701]: can't find host server 
Apr  2 14:13:22 hsystem1a ntpdate[12701]: can't find host server`. I don't understand why the hosts couldn't be found since I can easily SSH to them.. When I try `ntpdate 10.45.68.47` I get the following error ` 2 Apr 14:13:38 ntpdate[12712]: the NTP socket is in use, exiting`. Any ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: Oh, I figured out that ntpdate won't work as long as ntpd is running. So I stopped the ntpd and ran ntpdate 10.45.68.47. I got the following error this time: `2 Apr 14:28:11 ntpdate[20006]: no server suitable for synchronization found`.

Comment: Check that those two hostnames are resolvable from that machine (using either `nslookup` or `dig`). That last message means that that server isn't doing the ntp protocol (though it probably can be reached ok). Can you try pointing ntpdate to a known time server such as one from the pool? Then check that that 10.45.68.47 is serving up ntp and a firewall isn't blocking access to UDP port 123.

Comment: Unfortunately this machine does not have any access to outside world and I do not have a local "valid" NTP server here. I tried to use the `nslookup` as you've proposed and I've received the following output: `nslookup 10.45.68.47 ;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached`.

Comment: Well you can't use ntp then if you have no access to another ntp server. It won't work. When I said use nslookup, I meant something like `nslookup hsystem1a` which looks up the IP address for `hsystem1a`. By the looks of that message though, you don't have correct name servers set (so hostnames can't be turned into IP addresses). You need to put some into `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: Hmm.. It's strange since I can reach the target machine (10.45.68.47) using SSH with no problem. The hostnames are configured in `/etc/hosts` but I just used IPs directly rather than hostnames to eliminate additional issues.. Should there be any specific configuration on the machine I want to use as NTP? AFAIK I can configure just any linux machine with running `ntpd` on it.

Comment: NTP relies on a network of PCs set up as a pyramid. At the top is a machine connected to a definitive time source (usually a fountain style atomic clock at a government lab/uni). The next layer down connects to these machines and disseminates time to the next layer down. So you have to connect your machines to other NTP machines. It can't be independent unless you have a good time source in your environment. `nslookup` queries DNS servers. If you're not using DNS then don't worry about it.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I'd like to mention here that it's not very important for me that the time will be precise relative to the real time. I need to be only synchronized with the other server, that's all! And I'm not using DNS here so I can probably disregard the previous issue. Anyway, it still seems that there is some kind of connection problem but only NTP-wise. Is there anything else I can check or configure? Sorry, I'm little desperate here...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2983/discussion-between-webtoe-and-eugene-s)

Answer (score 2):

You're apparently using Debian.

Default config options are in `/etc/default/<daemon-name>`.

EDIT: okay, not Debian :)

The simple truth is that you cannot run ntpdate and ntpd on the same computer without a port collision - ntpd *listens* on UDP 123, and ntpdate *sends* from UDP 123.

Comment: Nevertheless it's RHEL :)

Comment: Did you check /etc/default ? :)

Comment: Yes I did, but there are only 2 nonrelated files (`nss` and `useradd`).

Comment: AH, I see in your log that it is in fact ntpdate interfering; this is annoying but happens a lot. ntpdate also uses the source port 123, which means ntpd cannot bind to it...

Comment: I was not aware of it. Isn't it a part of ntp startup/update process itself? These lines appear when I restart the ntpd service. Are you saying that I should configure the ports otherwise? Thanks!

Comment: No, ntpdate is completely separate and used to sync time at startup on machines that do not run a full ntpd service.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2969/discussion-between-eugene-s-and-adaptr)

Comment: ...no, it's a good question. It should be answered here.

Comment: I see. So do you have any idea where the NTP servers are configured for `ntpdate` service rather than for `ntpd`? Should I apply any additional configuration to make it work? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't run ntp server without connecting to another time server(source).

Comment: First: That's the very problem the OP wants to solve.  Second: Your statement is wrong anyway. a) You can define one system as your master time source and just make sure the other follows this (more or less wrong) time. It's not always important the time is correct but it's the same in all connected systems. b) You can use non-networked time sources like radio time signal or GPS receivers .